# Using quantile regression results to select and weight variables for models

Tags: predictive-models, feature-selection, quantile-regression, kurtosis

Linear regression is commonly used to identify predictor(s) (e.g., scores on cognitive ability or personality assessments) of job performance. Typically, predictors that exhibit a significant relationship with job performance are combined to create a composite and are weighted based on their relationship with job performance (i.e., regression-weighted composite). That composite is then used in the future to determine which candidates are most likely to succeed on the job and those with higher scores are deemed better fit. However, since the distribution of job performance is often heavy-tailed, linear regression assumptions are typically violated. Quantile regression serves as a nice alternative in this situation and provides much more nuanced information about the relationship between predictor and criterion. My question is, how could the more nuanced information from a quantile regression be used to make "smarter" decisions regarding which predictors should be included and how to weight them in the final composite?

Comment: What assumptions are violated? Distributional assumption (normality) is the least useful among regression assumptions as it does not impact consistency, asymptotic normality, efficiency (among linear unbiased) or unbiasedness of the OLS estimator. A violation can be dealt with rather easily by using bootstrap. Quantile regression could yield some more efficiency, but if the only assumption that is violated is normality, then it is probably not a big deal. But since you are considering quantile regression, I would think about other assumptions such as linearity and homoskedastisity.

Comment: Also, are you actually selecting variables (as your title suggests) or are you just weighing them? If you are, consider adding the [tag:feature-selection] tag.

Comment: Data often violate linearity and homoscedasticity as well. This would also include variable selection. Ultimately, the goal is to narrow the subset of predictors down to the most important, but also combine them into a final composite/model that can be used to make future predictions.

Comment: Quartile regression has the same linearity assumptions as OLS.